# Sort array of months with laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, collections, closures

My array is

```
$array = [
 1 => 0
 2 => 0
 3 => 0
 4 => 0
 5 => 0
 6 => 0
 7 => 2
 8 => 0
 9 => 0
 10 => 1
 11 => 0
 12 => 1
];
```

As a result i want it to be

```
$array = [
 10 => 1
 11 => 0
 12 => 1
 1 => 0
 2 => 0
 3 => 0
 4 => 0
 5 => 0
 6 => 0
 7 => 2
 8 => 0
 9 => 0
];
```

And my logic for now is

```
$sorted = collect($array)
  ->sortBy(function ($count, $month) {
    return $month <= 9;
  });
```

But the result is not what I expected :(

Basically i want last index to be current month and so on back.

Please help me!

Comment: As I wrote, I want the month 9 to be the last one key

Comment: can you put more examples of result, what happens when there's 20? Should it go top?

Comment: There are only 12 months ;) @nrkz So, if it's May(5), the array should look like [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5]?

Comment: kerbholz exactly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$sorted = collect($array)->sortBy(function ($count, $month) {
    $currentMonth = (int) \Carbon\Carbon::now()->month;

    return ($month + (12 - $currentMonth - 1)) % 12;
});
```

Comment: Perfect ;) Thank you!
->sortBy(function ($count, $month) {
                return ($month + (12 - Carbon::now()->month - 1)) % 12;
            });

Comment: You're welcome. I would definitely use `->month` as you suggested. I just used `->format('n')` as I remember it and didn't bother looking up the documentation for Carbon. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can function form php that

> krsort();

krsort can sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the key. So

```
ksort($array);
```